# Laravel make data unique but remove first duplicate

Tags: php, laravel

I got `data` from `db`:

```
$message = Message::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

*Result:*

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "post_id": 3,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "message": "hello",
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "post_id": 3,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "sender_id": 1,
        "message": "how are you?",
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "post_id": 3,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "message": "Ill call you",
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "post_id": 5,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "message": "hi hello",
        "status": 0
    }
]
```

Well, I able to make it unique and remove duplicate by `user_id` with:

```
$message->unique('user_id')
```

It return right result, but what I want is, remove first item not last, current result:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "post_id": 3,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "message": "hello",
        "status": 0
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 4,
        "post_id": 5,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "message": "hi hello",
        "status": 0
    }
}
```

As you see, it keep first item and then removed next duplicate, in this case I want to keep id `3` and `4` also it made my object to array, I don't want this, how can I solve this?

But I want this result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "post_id": 3,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "message": "Ill call you",
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "post_id": 5,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "message": "hi hello",
        "status": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: try to sort result by ID before call unique

Comment: `Message::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()->reverse()->unique('user_id')` ?

Comment: @Eugene Oh, I forgot `OrderBy` .. thanks it solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the newest messages try sorting on id in a descending order

```php
$messages = Message::where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

and you are receiving a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) you call toArray on it to get back an array:

```php
return $messages->unique('user_id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sorting before unique.

```
$message = Message::where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
$message->unique('user_id');
```